# Code analysis CA0001 error for project using NSubstitute

Tags: visual-studio-2010, code-analysis, mscorlib, nsubstitute

I have a (.NET 4) test project which references (the .NET 4) NSubstitute.dll.

When I run CodeAnalysis against the project I get a number of CA0001 errors:

Running Code Analysis...

> MSBUILD : error : CA0001 : The following error was encountered while reading module 'NSubstitute': Could not resolve type reference: [mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ExtensionAttribute.
>
> MSBUILD : error : CA0001 : Rule=Microsoft.Interoperability#CA1404, Target=arcplan.test.engage.admin.ecmFramework.CAppSettingsTest.#IsSettingsStoreReadyToUse_SettingsStoreIsNotReady_ReturnsFalse() : The following error was encountered while reading module 'ECMFrameworkTest': Method type parameter in position 0 is not valid.
>
> MSBUILD : error : CA0001 : Rule=Microsoft.Security#CA2122, Target=arcplan.test.engage.admin.ecmFramework.CAppSettingsTest.#IsSettingsStoreReadyToUse_SettingsStoreIsNotReady_ReturnsFalse() : The following error was encountered while reading module 'ECMFrameworkTest': Method type parameter in position 0 is not valid.

(etc.)

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using version 1.4.1? The build of this version had a problem caused by [using ilmerge with .NET 4.5 installed](http://www.mattwrock.com/post/2012/02/29/What-you-should-know-about-running-ILMerge-on-Net-45-Beta-assemblies-targeting-Net-40.aspx). This is fixed as of version 1.4.2 of NSubstitute (the latest release as of this comment).

More details are available on [the commit to fix this](https://github.com/nsubstitute/NSubstitute/commit/60486f5f83fddc92f77850e16cd29f129bd0c9b9).

Comment: I am using 1.4.1 - I will try with 1.4.2.I do not have .NET 4.5 installed.

Comment: yes! I upgraded to NSubstitute 1.4.2 and the code analysis runs. Many thanks.

Comment: @GarethOwen The problem was that the distributed binaries were built on a machine with .NET45 installed. Glad you got it sorted. Sorry for the inconvenience.